# shmat for attaching shared memory segment

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

When I looked through the man pages of `shmat`. It is described as the primitive function of the API is **to attach  the memory segment associated wih `shmid` it to the calling process' address space** .

The questions I have are the following.

- The term **attach** looks generic to me. I find difficulties in understanding what is the **underlying acivity** that attach refers to.?
- What it means by **mapping a segment of memory**?

Answer (score 2):

Use it as `char *ptr=shmat(seg_id,NULL,0);`
It attaches the created segment id by function `shmget()` with the process which contains this above code.

`seg_id` is the segment id of newly created segment
`NULL` means the Operating System will take care of the starting address of the segment on user's behalf
`0` is flag for `read/write` both

Whenever a process attaches to shared memory then it must be detached so that another process can access it by attaching to that segment (if the locking mechanism of resources is present.)

to detach : `shmdt(ptr);`

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation here: http://www.makelinux.net/alp/035

"Under Linux, each process's virtual memory is split into pages. Each process maintains a mapping from its memory addresses to these virtual memory pages, which contain the actual data. Even though each process has its own addresses, multiple processes' mappings can point to the same page, permitting sharing of memory"

Comment: Seems like they've got it wrong (in reverse). Each process has its own virtual address space and maintains a mapping from the virtual space to page frames in  the physical memory, where the data is located.